# Android Message Digest get most hashes right but not all

Tags: java, android, hash, message, digest

hi so I am trying to calculate the 3 different hashes which I will then later match up against my own database. The thing is that it seems that it does not always produce the correct hash. I know its not right because when I take the actual hash and write it in to VirusTotal, it can find it no problem, but when i try and calculate it using message digest it doesnt return the correct value.

Here is my code:

```
                try {

                    PackageInfo info = pm.getPackageInfo(
                            name, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);

                    for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                        MessageDigest md;

                        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                        md.update(signature.toByteArray());


                        byte[] messageDigestMD5 = md.digest();
                        StringBuffer stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
                        for (byte bytes : messageDigestMD5) {
                            stringBuffer.append(String.format("%02x", bytes & 0xff));
                        }
                        stringBuffer.append(" ");
                        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
                        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                        byte[] messageDigestSHA1 = md.digest();
                        for (byte bytes : messageDigestSHA1){
                            stringBuffer.append(String.format("%02x", bytes & 0xff));
                        }
                        stringBuffer.append(" ");
                        md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");
                        md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                        byte[] messageDigestSHA256 = md.digest();
                        for (byte bytes : messageDigestSHA256){
                            stringBuffer.append(String.format("%02x", bytes & 0xff));
                        }
                        res.setHash(stringBuffer.toString());
                    }

                } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e1) {
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }
```

So res.setHash(stringBuffer.toString()); is my own setter function that adds everything to a result list used in other parts. Again, it seems it will do approx, ~90% of hashes correctly.